# Anyone knows when is encoding needed

Tags: ruby

I have no idea when encoding is needed? Any pointers.

https://github.com/rack/rack/commit/76e75f6fffd8eaf58c612d658fe0be97a993b07f

Answer (score 1):

Without the encoding pragma Ruby (1.9 and above) will assume all literal strings in that file should be encoded as ASCII. If you want literal strings to contain say UTF-8 characters you have to tell Ruby that your source file is UTF-8, otherwise those strings will be treated as ASCII, and some characters will be garbled.

Comment: "and some characters will be garbled", or worse, the interpreter will complain.

Answer (score 0):

It's needed, when you want to use non-ASCII characters in your source code file. [more details.](http://blog.grayproductions.net/articles/ruby_19s_three_default_encodings)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be compatible with Ruby 1.9 and your file contains UTF-8 literals or comments, you need the encoding pragma.

If you can do with Ruby 2.x and up and do not have to be compatible with Ruby 1.9, the encoding pragma can be omitted *unless* your comments or literals in the file are in some other upper-ASCII or Kanji encoding that is not UTF-8.

Ruby 1.8 ignores the encoding pragma altogether.